# question about routing flight framework php

Tags: php, sql, frameworks

hi im using flight framework for routing and i have a question regarding following code examples. could you please help me guys)

function:

```
function getCoursesByStudents($students)    {

// 1. connection to dbms/db
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '....', 'university');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die($mysqli->connect_error);
}

// 2. query
$query = "SELECT cs.student_id, c.id, c.title FROM courses_students cs, courses c WHERE cs.course_id = c.id AND cs.student_id = " . $students;

$resulthandle = $mysqli->query($query);
if (!$resulthandle) {
    die($mysqli->error);
}

// 3. prepare and return result
$resultforclient = array();
while ($result = $resulthandle->fetch_assoc())  {
    $resultforclient[] = $result;

}

$resulthandle->close();
return $resultforclient;
```

}

routing:

```
Flight::route('/students/@id/courses', function($id){
$result = getCoursesByStudents($id);
echo json_encode($result);
```

});

may you please explain it to my step by step for the following example:

http://localhost/university/backend/flight-master/students/1/courses

my biggest problem is the understanding of the sql query part at the end after cs.studen_ id .. --> = " . $students;

how would the query be in mysql format?

im a newbie so please explain it to me the easy way.. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`$students` is a [parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)) of `getCoursesByStudents()`; when you invoke `getCoursesByStudents($id)`, you pass `$id` into this function, and the value of `$id` is passed through to the `$students` variable.

`$id` itself is determined by `Flight::route('/students/@id/courses'`, where the `@` denotes the [named parameter](https://github.com/mikecao/flight#named-parameters) in Flight, and this is grabbed from whatever is in the URL. As such, `@id` becomes `$id`, and ultimately `$students`.

This is passed into the query as:

```
$query = "SELECT cs.student_id, c.id, c.title FROM
courses_students cs, courses c WHERE cs.course_id = c.id AND cs.student_id = 1"
```

**However**, this is done in an insecure way, and leaves you open to a rather serious [security vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which would allow students to view other student's information.

Instead of passing the ID directly into the SQL statement (with `... cs.student_id = " . $students`), you should parameterise this query, making use of [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
$query = "SELECT cs.student_id, c.id, c.title FROM
courses_students cs, courses c WHERE cs.course_id = c.id AND cs.student_id = ?";
$query->bind_param("s", $students); 
$query->execute();
```